# What kind of cancer did Wade Wilson have?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

So Wade Wilson gets cancer, what was the original origin of the cancer?

When he originally is diagnosed we see some X-rays of the lungs,

[image]

But, when trying to leave Vanessa, he says this,

> You're right, the cancer is only in my liver, lungs, prostate and brain,
>   all things I can live without.

So what was the original cancer diagnosis?

Comment: I don't think it's ever stated...but it doesn't really matter once it's spread that far.

Comment: The origin was genetic. In the comics. his mother died of cancer at a young age.

Comment: @Valorum I think he means where did DP first develop it...but you're right.

Comment: The *quickest* way for a cancer to spread to many organs is with a part of the anatomy that has a lot of blood that passes through it, so my first guess would be the liver, and the second would be the brain..

Comment: @AndrewThompson, he has prostate cancer. I am a Doctor and he has prostate cancer by all the info given to us.

Comment: @KyloRen ..you do realise that checking testicles is no way to check for prostate cancer, right? *..right?!?*

Comment: @AndrewThompson, no need , the prostate is a unique organ. You should study more up on it if you are a male. And you are confusing testicular cancer to prostate cancer.

Comment: I could have sworn that he had _el_ cancer.

Comment: All the cancers...

Comment: [The kind you don't get better from.](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Watchmen.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at online movie scripts after he passes out it cuts to the hospital and shows the cancer everywhere, there is no specific description of were it started.

However, we do have a nice PSA by Deadpool about testicular cancer:

And fitting the humor of the movie, his cancer may have originated there, his **balls**.

As @Valorum points out, classically in the comics his mom dies of cancer as well, so it has a high chance of being due to some genetic influence, as well.

Comment: Given the blurb would have been crafted to fit a PSA, I doubt it really says anything about the origin of the cancer in-universe, and since the 'mother had cancer' mentioned in a comment above, I doubt it would have started in *her* testicles. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson just some fun speculation, since its pretty clear in the movie at least to have no origin. at least from online scripts

Comment: Well done Himarm, you figured it out. He has prostate cancer. Being a Doctor myself, as soon as he said 'prostate', the way cancer spreads, it could only be prostate cancer.

Comment: @KyloRen But Himarm answered testicular, not prostate. I'm confused as to why this answer has been accepted?

Comment: @Kwola-T hell get back to you in3 days when hes ususpended

Comment: @Kwola-T, although Himarm shows Testicular cancer testing that Deadpool is promoting, he mentions the PSA test which is specifically for testing Prostate cancer. I am not sure if that what he means with PSA, but that is good enough for me. I am not fusy.

Answer (score 8):

### He has Prostate Cancer.

Well Himarm has given the answer, but being a Doctor myself I think I should weigh in on this, prostate cancer is very rare in someone of the age of Wade Wilson, but it will spread quickly due to his age, hence the other places he has it. Also, the prostate is not an easily reached area by blood and will almost never be the place for cancer to spread to.